# Can someone explain me this recipe?

Tags: sed, makefile

```
$(Q)makedepend $(CFLAGS) -o.o -f- $< 2> nul: | sed -e s!$(<:.cpp=.o)!$@! -e s!\\!/!g > $(@:.o=.d)
```

It is part of following rule in contiki makefile.

```
CUSTOM_RULE_CPP_TO_OBJECTDIR_O = 1
$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(OBJECTDIR)
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)cl -nologo $(VCFLAGS) -c $< -Fo$@
    $(Q)makedepend $(CFLAGS) -o.o -f- $< 2> nul: | sed -e s!$(<:.cpp=.o)!$@! -e s!\\!/!g > $(@:.o=.d)
```

Please let me know if you want more info before downvoting. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want explained.  This is a command line which invokes the `makedepend` program, redirects its stderr to `nul:` (looks like this expects to be run on a DOS system?  But using UNIX tools like sed?) and sends its output to `sed`.  The `sed` program is converting the `.o` filename in the makedepend output to the actual target name (including the path), and converting backslashes to forward slashes.

Then the results are written to a `.d` file.  Presumably somewhere in the makefile you'll find a line that uses `include` to include all the `.d` files.

Basically, this is a way of auto-generating header file dependencies so that make will rebuild object files when they change, without you having to write them all by hand in the makefile.

*ETA*

- **$(Q)**
  A make variable reference which probably expands to either `@` or not, to control verbosity of the makefile.
- **makedepend $(CFLAGS) -o.o -f- $<**
  Invoke `makedepend` with the `CFLAGS` options and write the results to stdout (`-f-`), reading the source file (`$<`)
- **2> nul:**
  Redirect stderr to `nul:` which on Windows is a special character device which means "throw it away".
- **|**
  Send the output of the previous command to the input of the next command.
- **sed**
  Run the sed (*stream editor*) program, which is a UNIX/POSIX program that manipulates files on a line-by-line basis (usually).
- **-e s!$(<:.cpp=.o)!$@!**
  The first manipulation substitutes the plain name of the object file (e.g., if you're compiling `foo.cpp` then `$<` is `foo.cpp`, and `$(<:.cpp=.o)` replaces the `.cpp` with a `.o` so the result is `foo.o`) with the name of the target: `$@` will be the full target name like `obj/foo.o`, if `OBJECTDIR` is `obj`.
- **-e s!\\!/!g**
  The second substitution replaces all backslashes (escaped from the shell, so `\\`) with forward slashes.
- **> $(@:.o=.d)**
  Write the output of the sed command to the file `$@` with the `.o` replaced by `.d`, so if `OBJECTDIR` is `obj` it will write to `obj/foo.d`

Comment: I understood the point, thank you for that but can you please break the statement and explain which part is doing what?